# Listing files in GridFS directory using Ruby driver

Tags: ruby, gridfs

Is it possible to list all files in given GridFS directory using ruby mongo driver?
I've searched through documentation and have not found anything satisfying. What is more I cannot find any way to search files by metadata too.
I have checked java driver's documentation and both of these functionalities are available out of the box using GridFS class.

Best regards,

Michał

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = Mongo::Grid.new(Mongoid.database)
files = grid.instance_variable_get :@files
files.find("filename" => "uploads/143-normal_regular2.jpg").as_json

# files.remove - deletes alle files
```

same works for chunks